# Julia how to get coefficients out of SymPy solveset

Tags: julia, sympy

I'm using symbolic math in Julia. When I do the differentiation it comes out very nicely, but I cant get the coefficients out

```
using SymPy
@vars x y
z = x*(10 + 5*x + 4*y)
dz = diff(z,x)
x_s = solveset(dz,x)
```

how do I get the the coefficients out of x_s?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there are accessor functions in SymPy.jl, but you can do `julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[1]
-1

julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[2]
-2⋅y
─────
  5

julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[2].__pyobject__.args[1]
-2/5`

Comment: Beautiful! thats what i was looking for. I can probably make a function to make it look cleaner. Let me know if there is a more direct answer. If not submit this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: It may be easier if you use `solve` instead of `solveset`.

Answer (score 4):

You can  use `elements`  to get the elements of a finite sets as an array:

```
julia> elements(s)
1-element Array{Sym,1}:
 -2*y/5 - 1
```

To get the coefficients can be done different  ways,  but here we convert the value  to a Polynomial  type, then use  its  `coeffs`  method:

```
julia> p = sympy.Poly(elements(s)[1], y)
Poly(-2/5*y - 1, y, domain='QQ')

julia> p.coeffs()
2-element Array{Sym,1}:
 -2/5
   -1
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, the following works but isn't exactly what I'd describe as pretty:

```
julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[1] 
-1  

julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[2] 
-2⋅y 
─────
  5  

julia> x_s.__pyobject__.args[1].__pyobject__.args[2].__pyobject__.args[1]
 -2/5
```

I couldn't find an accessor function in Sympy.jl that simplifies this, but as you say this could be the basis for rolling your own.